# Using SBT to drive a build Java+Scala build that includes SWIG and C++ compilation

Tags: scala, sbt, swig

I am about to write the build configuration for a (mostly) SWIG'd wrap of a C++ library to be callable from Scala. Due to the presence of 3rd party dependencies on the Scala side, as well vast community support, I'd like to use sbt to automate the build.

However, I am a bit at a loss as to automating the swig and c++ compilation steps. Does anyone have experience with mixed-language build configurations driven by sbt and can offer advice about this?

So far I have found about the [sbt-sh](https://github.com/steppenwells/sbt-sh) plugin, but I'd rather avoid shelling out directly if possible. I have also considered using cmake as the driver (since cmake does have a swig-driver plugin), and have a java/scala-only build step fired off cmake after it has completed the swig and c++ build steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SBT has its own syntax for executing external processes. You can leverage this + path finding + source generation.

A rough example:

```
lazy val invokeSwig = taskKey[Seq[File]]("invoke swig")
invokeSwig := {
  s"swig -java example.i -outdir ${target.value}" !
  val pathFinder = target.value ** "*.java"
  pathFinder.get
}
target in invokeSwig := target.value / "swig"
sourceGenerators in Compile <+= invokeSwig
```

*Note: I am using sbt v0.13.9, but this should work in other versions too.*

You'd have to do some additional work for the native components. This includes compiling them as well as ensuring that they are available during run.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to accept this answer, even though irundaia's has more details on the shelling-out part, because it clarifies the path finding part.

Comment: Cool! I suppose I could expand the answer a bit to be more comprehensive-- I just feel silly copying the content from someone else's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can get around doing some shell scripting since swig is a command line tool.  (I have not found any java wrappers.)

SBT has the concept of source generators. A source generator is nothing more than a function/task writing (and returning) some files. If you do this, then SBT will first execute all source generators before starting to compile the (rest of the) code.

Just make sure to get swig to output its files to `sourceManaged in Compile`, then the generated source files are available on the classpath during compilation.

```
def runSwig: Seq[File] = {
  import sys.process._
  Seq("swig" , "param1", "param2", "..." ).!
  // Somehow determine which files have been written by swig.
  // I would make swig output its files to a temp directory and copy them to the source managed directory manually.
}

sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
  runSwig
}
```

I'm not sure about C++ code though. In my own project I'm using docker to cross compile to various platforms. If your native code doesn't change often, I won't recommend recompiling the native code every time SBT is compiling your java/scala code.